# Why are these two LINQ queries different? When they seem to be the same

Tags: c#, linq

I would like know why these two LINQ queries are different, or why one works and the other does not? Obviously the compiler says they are different, but I can't seem to find out why?

I want the first query to work, but no matter what I do It won't work.

The below LINQ query gives me an error of,

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

```
public static IEnumerable<int?> GetTenantFacilityCosts(int? code, DateTime date, int number)
    {
        return DataContext.Facility_Cost_TBLs.
               Where(p => p.Tenant_Code == code &&
                          p.Code_Date == number &&
                          p.Date_Year == date.Year &&
                          p.Date_Month == date.Month).
                          FirstOrDefault().Tenant_Portion;
    }
```

But this query below gets the `int` value that I am trying to get and does not throw an error.

```
int? facilityCost = 
        DataContext.Facility_Cost_TBLs.
        Where(p => p.Tenant_Code == selectedTenant.Tenant_Code &&
                   p.Code_Date == 10 &&
                   p.Date_Year == date.Year &&
                   p.Date_Month == date.Month).
                   FirstOrDefault().Tenant_Portion;
```

Why are these two queries differnt and how would I get the first one to work correctly?

Comment: The error tells you that you're trying to return an `int?` in a method that should return an `IEnumerable<int?>`.

Comment: change `return` to `yield return` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linq query returns a nullable int i.e. `int?`, the reason it works for the second is because it is assigning the value to a `int?`.

The second one is returning a `int?` on a method that is trying to return: `IEnumerable<int?>`. If you want to return an enumerable of the results you need to remove the `FirstOrDefault` from the query. And judging by the method name, i.e. the plural `Costs`, this is what you want.

However if you only want one result change the method signature to:

```
public static int? GetTenantFacilityCosts(int? code, DateTime date, int number)
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from the one that works, the result of your query is an `int?`. When you've turned that to a function the return type of your function is `IEnumerable<int?>`.

You function should be

```
public static int? GetTenantFacilityCosts(int? code, DateTime date, int number)
{
  ...
}
```